# How to access Chromebook Settings from Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I am trying to open a specific Settings page in a Chromebook using my Android app (Settings -> Device -> Storage Management -> External storage preferences).

My app reads/writes the USB drive, and I need to ensure that this is enabled. If this is enabled, everything works great, but I need an easy way to point the user to this setting.

If I open chrome://os-settings/storage/externalStoragePreferences in a Chrome browser it takes me to the correct setting.

I've tried using opening in a browser using:

`val uri = Uri.parse("http://chrome://ossettings/storage/externalStoragePreferences")`

`val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)`

`startActivity(browserIntent)`

This gives a 'site can't be reached' error.

If I try without http - just using chrome://ossettings/storage/externalStoragePreferences as the uri, I get the following error:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=chrome://os-settings/storage/externalStoragePreferences cmp=org.chromium.arc.intent_helper/.OpenChromeMultideviceSettingsActivity } from ProcessRecord{cc19980 19710:com.simplifieditproducts.picturekeeperconnect/u0a69} (pid=19710, uid=10069) requires com.google.android.apps.multidevice.client.permission.INITIALIZE_SCAN`

This is my first time working with Chrome OS, and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation available. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the used intent code.

Comment: Also post the code for an intent to open a browser to display a certain page.

Comment: I updated my question to include the intent code. Thanks!

Comment: `This gives a 'site can't be reached' error.`. Who is telling you that? Android? Chrome? Is Chrome started?

Comment: `com.google.android.apps.multidevice.client.permission.INITIALIZE_SCAN`. What have you done to obtain that permission?

Comment: Yea Chrome is launched, but it won't open the page if the url is prefixed with http. If it's not prefixed with http then it crashes giving that permissions error. I tried adding it to the manifest file, but it made no difference. I also can't find it anywhere in the documentation so I'm not quite sure what it's referencing or how I would properly request it.

Comment: So the settings are opened if you type that url (without http://) in the address bar of Crome? Or how do you otherwise open those settings?

Comment: Make a html page with a link for your url. Maybe it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried with an html page and get the webpage about:blank#blocked when I try to open chrome://ossettings/storage/externalStoragePreferences.